# Using arecord and aplay to transfer audio over a network

Tags: c

I have established a TCP connection between a client and a host. The idea is that the host will request an audio file from the client. At this point, the client will record what is coming through the mic and then send it back to the host.

Using arecord for the client and aplay for the host, how would I go about doing this?
I have spent the best part of 24 hours trying to work this out but just cannot do so!

Really hope someone can help and if any additional information is needed, just let me know.

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to program this in C, or are you trying to use the `arecord` program?  Or are you actually invoking arecord from a C program?  If it's the latter, I'd say stop and rethink your approach--surely there is a more suitable language than C for that.

Comment: I'm trying to program it in C. I have to pass the audio that arecord produces across the TCP network and play it on the other host machine. It's killing me, I just need some pointers as where to go!

Answer (score 1):

TCP is difficult to make work correctly as you really need to use the UDP protocol for real-time transmissions.  TCP will always exhibit lag, and that lag will get worse over time. The reason is because as soon as a packet is dropped, TCP will try to auto recover the packet, thus introducing more lag delay in real-time transmissions.  On the other hand, UDP will ignore dropped packets, keeping your real-time interface current.  On Wi-Fi, dropped packets are common, so this issue is very noticeable.

[GStreamer](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/) is pretty easy to get working over UDP.  I'm sure there's a way to get gstreamer to work with arecord and aplay, but there's really no need as gstreamer supports [ALSA](https://alsa-project.org/wiki/Main_Page) directly.   Example:

Microphone on client (192.168.44.10)  Transmitting to remote host (192.168.44.1):

```
 $ gst-launch-1.0 alsasrc device=hw:2,0 ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! alawenc ! rtppcmapay ! udpsink host=192.168.44.1 port=5002
```

Server host (192.168.44.1) {receiver}  Speakers:

```
$ gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=5002 caps=application/x-rtp ! rtppcmadepay ! alawdec ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! alsasink device=hw:1,0
```

Use "aplay -l" to determine the hardware device number of your sound card(s).  For instance this is the output on my server host, which has the speakers attached:

```
$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Headphones [bcm2835 Headphones], device 0: bcm2835 Headphones [bcm2835 Headphones]
  Subdevices: 8/8
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
  Subdevice #1: subdevice #1
  Subdevice #2: subdevice #2
  Subdevice #3: subdevice #3
  Subdevice #4: subdevice #4
  Subdevice #5: subdevice #5
  Subdevice #6: subdevice #6
  Subdevice #7: subdevice #7
card 1: Device [Generic USB Audio Device], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Answer (score 0):

You say you need to do this in C.  I suggest then that you use a library rather than an external program to do the audio processing.  But most of all I would urge you to stop using C for this, it's not particularly well-suited to the task.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout:

http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=52934

they use netcat to handle the socket/network stuff...